# Finding a tuple-value through a randomized tuple

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

lets say I have the following list of tuples:

```
colours = [('green', 1.4), ('blue', 4.067), ('yellow', 6.56), ('black', 9.056), ('red', 10.23)]
```

I have randomized one of these values thorough the following code and got the index of that value in the list:

```
colour_name = random.choice(colours)[0]
colour_number = [i for i, t in enumerate(colours) if t[0] == colour_name][0] + 1
```

Lets say I have randomized the colour green with the index 0. How do I also get the value 1.4 that belongs to green?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my view, you should follow this approach - this way, you have access to both the randomized (colour, float) and its index (1 based):

```
chosen = random.choice(colours)

i = colours.index(chosen) + 1

print(chosen)
print(i)
```

If color and float number are needed in 2 separate variables:

```
colour, float_number = chosen
```

Comment: I see your point but i need the color and the float number to be seperated in two variables